# Repeat function not working

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

Right now I have multiple dialog boxes, and have written the following so that the right button opens up the right dialog box.

```
$(function() {
var i = 0;
if (i < 50) {
    i++;
        $( ".dialog" + i ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 900,
            show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        }
        });
        $( ".opener" + i ).click(function() {
            $( ".dialog" + i ).dialog( "open" );
        });
    }
});
```

However, nothing happens now when I click on the buttons. 
What am I missing here?

Comment: want you change `if` to `while` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a simpler solution for this just to demonstrate the right technique.
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="open" data-modalID="1">open 1</li>
    <li class="open" data-modalID="2">open 2</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="modal modal_1">Hi, I'm modal 1</li>
    <li class="modal modal_2">Hi, I'm modal 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.modal { display: none; }
```

jQuery:

```
(function() {
    $('.open').on('click', function() {
        var modalID =  $(this).attr('data-modalID');

        $('.modal_' + modalID).show();
    });
})();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/YAkpq/

Comment: This is great! How would I go about creating the 'close' button?

Comment: You can use the same code, just change the button class to «close» instead of «open» and in JS change «.show()» to «.hide()», if I understood you clearly :)

Comment: awesome, is there any special way I need to organize these two chunks of code (the opening and the closing), it's opening up just dandy but the close button doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Thank you! You rock javakorr!

Answer (score 0):

use while(){} instead of if(){}

```
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    while (i < 50) {
        i++;
            $( ".dialog" + i ).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 900,
                show: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 500
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 500
            }
            });
            $( ".opener" + i ).click(function() {
                $( ".dialog" + i ).dialog( "open" );
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: hmmm now both dialog boxes are hidden by default (awesome), but clicking on the button doesn't do anything now.